# PayPal and currency exchange rate

Tags: paypal, currency

I want to get the best currency exchange rate ( usd to euro ) when i withdraw my funds to bank account.The problem is that i don't want to log in every day to check it.
I want to be notified when there is a fixed change.

So,what do you think is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Unanswerable. You are asking for a means to predict the future. There is no way of knowing whether tomorrow's exchange rate will be better than today's.